# Wrapper a class(Native c++) using managed C++, how to do about the native struct?

Tags: c#, struct, managed-c++

```
namespace mcWrapper {
struct S1
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
};
class C1
{
public:
    void Test(S1* ps1)
    {

    };
};

public ref class Class1Wrapper
{
public:
    Class1Wrapper()
    {           
        _pC1 = new C1();
    };
    void Test(S1* ps1)
    {
        _pC1->Test(ps1);
    }
private:
    C1* _pC1;
};}
```

Build it, we can get a .net dll .

Create an C# client to use this dll:

```
//c#    
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        var c1 = new mcWrapper.Class1Wrapper();
        //we can find Test method , but we cannot type codes like: s1*
        c1.Test()//?????????????????????????????????

    }
```

I cannot run Class1Wrapper.Test in c#.

Then I have tried to change Test() to Test( int^ n),
I found c# explain Test(int^n) as Test(ValueType n)
I have been confused, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

So, what i should do is set a new managed struct like:

```
public value struct CsS1{int n1;int n2}
```

And Then change Test(...) from

```
Class1Wrapper::Test(S1* ps1){_pc1->Test(ps1);}
```

To

```
Class1Wrapper::Test(CsS1* pcs1)
{
    S1* ps1 = new S1(); 
    ps1.n1=pcs1.n1; 
    ps1.n2=pcs.n2;
    _pc1->Test(ps1);
    delete ps1;
}
```

Its a hard work for wrapper. and i think it is wasting time .     There is no other way else？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your question to add additional information, including the information on this answer.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do it simpler. And if `S1` was a more complex class I would even do it more complicated by letting `CsS1` wrap a `S1` pointer.